# Aurelia - event load / "lazy load" images

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm very new to Aurelia, but I am enjoying it so far.  I want to make sure that I'm doing this the "Aurelia" way - and I'm not missing something because my new-platform-spidey-senses™ are telling me that I'm doing something wrong.

For now i'm simply trying to change the class of an image `onLoad` for "animations, pretty loading, and such"...(clients)

My approach thus far:

**template**

```
<template>
  <div class="random" repeat.for="thumb of thumbs">
    <img 
        alt="thumb.name" 
        src.bind-one-time="${server}/${thumb.uri}"
        load.trigger="loaded(thumb)"
        class.bind="thumb.loaded"
        class="lazyload"
     />
  </div>
</template>
```

**view-model**

```
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client'
import environment from './environment'

export class App {

  constructor() {
    this.client = new HttpClient()
    this.thumbs = []
    this.loaded = t => { t.loaded = 'loaded' }
  }

  activate() {
    return this.client.fetch(`${environment.api}/api`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.data = data
        this.thumbs = data.map(item => {
          if (item.thumbnails)
            return item.thumnails
        )}
      )}
    }
  }
```

This is abridged code -- trying to keep things legible.
Nearest I can tell `event.trigger` (as apposed to `event.delegate`) is necessary in this instance, and using the already bound thumb data is probably my best bet.

Thoughts...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks pretty good to me. Here's a few tweaks you could try that might streamline the code a bit:

**https://gist.run?id=251638547841a34746d9cbd874da14e2**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div repeat.for="thumb of thumbs">
    <img 
      alt.one-time="thumb.name" 
      src.one-time="server + '/' + thumb.uri"
      load.trigger="$event.target.classList.add('loaded') & oneTime"
      class="thumbnail"
     />
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  server = 'https://i.imgur.com';
  thumbs = [
    { name: 'SpaceX', uri: 'xSraADG.jpg' },
    { name: 'SpaceX', uri: 'HSeX7Nn.jpg' },
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - good call on the `& oneTime`  I didn't know that was possible. As well as the $event.target being placed in the load.trigger.  I'm glad to know i'm on the right track then.